# What's wrong with my code? Trying to find an element in a list

Tags: if-statement, haskell

This code should tell you whether or not an element a is in a list.
What is wrong with this code?

```
istEnthalten:: a -> [a] -> Bool
istEnthalten elem [] = False
istEnthalten elem (x:xs) = if elem == x
  then True
  else istEnthalten elem xs
```

I know this one works:

```
istEnthalten :: a -> [a] -> Bool
istEnthalten elem [] = False
istEnthalten elem (x:xs)
      | elem == x = True
      | otherwise = contains elem xs
```

but what`s wrong with the first one?

Comment: The first one looks fine to me except you've missed the necessary `Eq a` constraint in the type signature. GHC will point this out (it's always advisable, if asking about compiler errors you don't understand, to include the error message in the question).

Comment: Adding to @RobinZigmond’s comment, the `Eq a` constraint is necessary because you are seeing if `elem == x`; the `Eq a` constraint tells GHC that it is possible to use `(==)` with types of type `a`.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond @bradrn thank you :) I recently started learning Haskell.. where should I put the Eq a? ```istEnthalten:: a -> [a] -> Bool
istEnthalten elem [] = False
istEnthalten elem (x:xs) = if elem Eq x
  then True
  else istEnthalten elem xs ``` doesn't work either

Comment: In the type signature: `istEnthalten:: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`

Answer (score 1):

```
istEnthalten :: a -> [a] -> Bool
```

is the signature of a function that's able to find elements in a list of *any* type. I.e. it would even allow you to do stuff like this:

```
collatz :: Integer -> Integer

main = print $ collatz `istEnhalten` [const 1]
```

That can't possibly work. What doesn't work is that `Integer -> Integer` functions can *not* be equality-compared.

The `istEnthalten` function needs to be restricted to those types that *can* be equality-compared, i.e. the signature needs to be

```
istEnthalten :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

With that signature, both of your attempts do work. Note however

- [`elem`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) is already the name of the standard function that does the whole thing you're implementing here. Therefore, you should avoid using `elem` as a variable name, though it is technically possible (your name *shadows* the standard one within your function).
- `True` of `False` as one `if` branch is unnecessarily complicating things. Your logic is better expressed with boolean operators:

  ```
  istEnthalten e (x:xs) = e==x || istEnthalten e xs
  ```

  (Similarly, there's never a good reason to write `a==True`, that's the same as just `a`.)

Here's how I would do the task:

```
infix 4 ∈
(∈) :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
_ ∈ [] = False
a ∈ x:xs = a==x || a∈xs
```

Comment: For readability, I’d suggest not making the example use an infix operator. While it’s going to be barely noticeable for someone who’s experienced with the language, an infix function definition adds additional confusion to someone who is already going to be a bit confused just by the concept of type constraints.